# MemoryError in imgaug batch processing

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory

I have memory error issue even with a batch size of 32.

I'm trying to setup an input pipeline for yolo object detector. For every batch I have an `image_batch` numpy array `(32,416,416,3)`. I set up a augumentation pipeline of resize, flip, noise...etc. (note: I am not setting up a seq(list) in advance and using it. I am updating the list for every batch) When i run this, i get an error:

> Memory Error: np.zeros(output_shape, images.dtype) at Resize()

How can i solve this?

Comment: have you tried to lower the batch size? try if it works with batch size = 1 and then increase, and see when it will fail

Comment: Can you post your code? Usually batch size problem related to `Cuda out of memory`, but your error probably related to image processing